# How to perform good looking segue on new iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I'm looking for the best way to perform good looking segue.

My main goal is avoid the gap on the top of the screen and fill the whole screen (on iPhone 11 or XR etc.).

[Here you can see what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFNRl.png) (I used common Present Modally segue)

What solution are you using in your apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modalPresentationStyle` is required to be set on the `ViewController` which is being presented.

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

and From `storyboard` you can do it like this

[image]

Comment: you right. thank you very much. sorry for beginners question, somehow I overlook this property :(

Comment: please upvote if it resolve your issue

Comment: now you can do that .. happy coding =)

Comment: Be aware that the sheet modal presentation style is the default for iOS 13 and isn't specific to phone models. If possible and where it makes sense, you should embrace this presentation style